# Term to abuse one who doesn't deserve to be called a man

Tags: single-word-requests

Say a gang of many men beat a single guy Tom. Tom is a right guy but the gang is of cheap mentality. So, Tom wants to use an abusive and demeaning word for the gang and says you all are "xxx". He wants to say them that they all don't deserve to be called a man (they are cowards). Can the term " impotent " fits the context of Tom or any other term is used in such context? What's the term that's generally used by guys in Tom's shoes to abuse the gang?

Comment: There are lots of words that mean this, or something very similar, and different people wouold use different ones. A thesaurus would give you [a list](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/unmanly?s=t).

Comment: They're just **bullies.**

Comment: Impotent implies they can't **do anything** - but they can: they can beat the crap out of him.  So it's definitely not right.  There are a rich variety of abusive and demeaning words you could choose from, it's hard to say what's "right".  I think "cowards" which you mention, or "bullies" as @NVZ says, fit well if you want to keep it clean.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *Tom is a right guy*, but I'd say anyone who insults a bunch of guys who've just beaten him up isn't quite right in the head. Would he think he'd "won" if he came up with a good insult, but got hospitalized in the process?

Comment: I was about to say something similar. Anyone who has been beaten up *knows* that he had better keep his mouth shut. He's outnumbered, he's injured, the gang are euphoric and he wants to *insult* them?!

Comment: @Mari-Lou yes you're right. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Impotent doesn't fit.  NVZ is right.  Bullies is the best term.  They aren't impotent because they were able to beat him up.  Even if it fits, it sounds pretentious.

Cowards, which the OP mentions, could also fit.  "It took all of you to beat up one guy, you bunch of cowards!" or using sarcasm "You guys are brave.  It only took your entire gang to beat me up."

Answer (score 0):

[Pantywaist, mongrel, punk-ass bitch, worthless, dickless, fink, eunuch, wannabe pathetic, worthless, useless, nothing, sad, feeble minded,base, basic, little boys] I disagree about the "impotent." Sure,  they bested Tom physically, but they've all shown their mental impotence. I think it's a great insult if not meant to be taken literally/physically. And anyone who doesn't talk a little crap after getting their ass kicked is, indeed a pantywaist. You may have lost, but you still get the last shot in. Moreover, they truly are cowards for this action; they should be told. Tom should be the one to tell them. He's earned it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've certainly never heard of *pantywaist* although apparently it means [*sissy*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pantywaist). The other answer is now quite old, and standards have evolved over the last few years: please include corroboration for your suggestions.